# What is the difference between AddSingleton in .net core and creating the SingleTon Object in c#?

Tags: c#, singleton, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to understand what is the difference between `AddSingleton<>()` method implementation in .NET Core, and the method implementation if  singleton object creation in C#?

Comment: To use or not to use the DI, that's the question.

Comment: `AddSingleton` method tells the DI to create only one object of the registered class is created when resolved at runtime. How it is done by the DI, we don't need to worry about it. Singleton pattern implemented by ourselves involves private constructor, static property etc. They are not needed whey register as singleton in DI.